# Passing arrays as arguments to a function without passing their length to that function

Tags: c, arrays, function, argument-passing

I read that while passing an array as argument we must also have to pass its length as argument( strict C89 ).
In this given code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_RANKS 13
#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define NUM_CARDS 5

bool straight, flush, four, three;
int pairs;

void read_cards(int a[], int b[]);      // I did't specify the length in this declaration
void analyze_hand(int a[], int b[]);    // I did't specify the length in this declaration
void print_result(void);

int main()
{
    int num_in_rank[NUM_RANKS];
    int num_in_suit[NUM_SUITS];

    for(;;)
    {
        read_cards(num_in_rank, num_in_suit);
        analyze_hand(num_in_rank, num_in_suit);
        print_result();
    }
}

void read_cards(int num_in_rank[], int num_in_suit[])
{
    bool card_exists[NUM_RANKS][NUM_SUITS];
    char ch, rank_ch, suit_ch;
    int rank, suit;
    bool bad_card;
    int cards_read = 0;

    for(rank = 0; rank < NUM_RANKS; rank++)
    {
        num_in_rank[rank] = 0;
        for(suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
            card_exists[rank][suit] = false;        
    }

    for(suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
        num_in_suit[suit] = 0;

    while(cards_read < NUM_CARDS)
    {
        bad_card = false;

        printf("Enter a card: ");
        rank_ch = getchar();
        switch(rank_ch)
        {
            case '0':           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    case '2':           rank = 0; break;
                    case '3':           rank = 1; break;
                    case '4':           rank = 2; break;
                    case '5':           rank = 3; break;
                    case '6':           rank = 4; break;
                    case '7':           rank = 5; break;
                    case '8':           rank = 6; break;
                    case '9':           rank = 7; break;
                    case 't': case 'T': rank = 8; break;
                    case 'j': case 'J': rank = 9; break;
                    case 'q': case 'Q': rank = 10; break;
                    case 'k': case 'K': rank = 11; break;
                    case 'a': case 'A': rank = 12; break;
                    default:            bad_card = true;                        
         }

         suit_ch = getchar();
         switch(suit_ch)
         {
            case 'c': case 'C': suit = 0;  break;
            case 'd': case 'D': suit = 1;  break;
            case 'h': case 'H': suit = 2;  break;
            case 's': case 'S': suit = 3;  break;
            default:            bad_card = true;
         }

        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
            if(ch != ' ')
                bad_card = true;

        if(bad_card)
            printf("Bad card; ignored.\n");
        else if(card_exists[rank][suit])
            printf("Duplicate card; ignored.\n");
        else
        {
            num_in_rank[rank]++;
            num_in_suit[suit]++;
            card_exists[rank][suit] = true;
            cards_read++;
        }               
    }   
 }

void analyze_hand(int num_in_rank[], int num_in_suit[])
{
    int num_consec = 0;
    int rank, suit;

    straight = false;
    flush = false;
    four = false;
    three = false;
    pairs = 0;

    for(suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
        if(num_in_suit[suit] == NUM_CARDS)
            flush = true;
    rank = 0; 
    while(num_in_rank[rank] == 0)
        rank++;
    for(; rank < NUM_RANKS && num_in_rank[rank] > 0; rank++ )
        num_consec++;

    if(num_consec == NUM_CARDS)
    {
        straight = true;
        return;
    }

    for(rank = 0; rank < NUM_RANKS; rank++)
    {
        if(num_in_rank[rank] == 4)
        four = true;
        if(num_in_rank[rank] == 3)
        three = true;
        if(num_in_rank[rank] == 2)
           pairs++;     
    }       
}
```

I passed the two arrays `num_in_rank[NUM_RANKS]` and `num_in_suit[NUM_SUITS]` together to the functions `void read_cards(int a[], int b[])` and `void analyze_hand(int a[], int b[])` without supplying the arrays length and I don't know how this worked(without any warning/error)?
Any idea is it right or wrong?

Comment: sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) that might work

Comment: I think it depends upon how you use the functions.

Comment: The compiler knows nothing about semantics (well, let's not consider optimizations). So it can't tell you that "hey, this is a function which you should pass another length argument to!"...

Comment: @GregBrown; No that's not my problem. My problem is that how it is working without passing size of arrays to the function?

Comment: @H2CO3; This not the answer of this question!

Comment: It works probably because your array is on the stack. It most certainly won't work if you allocate your arrays using `malloc()`.

Comment: @Asblarf; Your comment confused me o.O.

Comment: @GregBrown; OK, tell me how `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` will work if the length of `a` is not specified??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that while passing an array as argument we must also have to pass its length as argument

This applies only in situations when the function does not know the size of the array upfront. When the function knows that the array must have a certain number of elements, you do not need to pass the size to the function.

This is exactly what is happening in your code: both functions that receive arrays know that `num_in_rank` contains exactly `NUM_RANKS` elements, and `num_in_suit` contains exactly `NUM_SUITS` elements. That is why you do not need to pass the size, and nothing is going to happen: the function already knows the size through `#define`d constants.

On the other hand, if you needed to pass an array of size unknown to your function, then you would need to do one of the following:

- Pass the number of elements in your array, or
- Pass a pointer to the last element (or one past the last element) of your array, or
- Agree on a "sentinel" value such as zero or negative one that would indicate the end of the valid range of data in your array.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array in c, all the function sees is a pointer to the start of the array, so the length is not visible inside the function.

In order to allow the function to use the length, you have to either create some kind of struct that also contains the length, have some kind of special character at the end of the valid input to the array (like '\0' for strings), or expicitly pass in the size as a function argument.

You won't get compile errors if you don't pass in the length, but most operations that you do on the array will require you to know how long it is, so you're likely going to get a segfault when you try to do operations on the array without knowing its length.

Edit:

After posting the full code, it's because you are using the macros for bounds checking, which is sort of like passing in the size, but less flexible.

Comment: But I did't get any segmentation fault?

Comment: All that means is that you're not reading past the end of the array.  The point is that you have no guarantees.  If you post the implementation of the functions, we might be able to explain why.  Probably it's because you wrote the functions with knowledge about the length of the array.  In C you are responsible for checking bounds.  It's not that you WILL get a seg fault, it's that you CAN and you have no way of verifying one or the other by looking at the function alone, without knowledge of the caller.

Comment: What do you mean by less flexible?

Comment: @haccks He means that you must recompile your code in order to change the size of your array (as opposed to, say, reading the number from `stdin` and allocating an array dynamically).

Comment: To understand why it's a good practice to pass in the size, consider the following scenario: You want to write a card playing application and someone has provided some functions for you called `analyze_hand` and `read_cards`. You can't (or don't have the time to) see the function implementation, but look at the prototype to understand how to use these functions.

Comment: So all you know is what you can see from the prototype, which is that you need to pass in two arrays of integers.  How big should those arrays be in order to be used successfully with these functions?  Also, with regard to flexibility, imagine a situation in which the total number of cards in the deck was determined at runtime.  How, then do you provide bounds checking in your function?

Comment: In run time situation it will get segmentation fault. I got your point , what you mean by flexible. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that arrays in C are essentially pointers to the beginning of the memory block that your program setting aside.  So when you say

```
int num_in_rank[NUM_RANKS];
int num_in_suit[NUM_SUITS];
```

you can use them as pointers.  It is usually in practice to also pass the size as an int, such as

```
void read_cards(int a[], int b[], int a_size, int b_size);
void analyze_hand(int a[], int b[], int a_size, int b_size);
```

if you need to utilize the size of the array.  But to answer your question there is no problem in doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on Visual Studio on how the compiler is doing the name mangling for various function declarations -

```
void foo(int a[]);
void foo(int a[10]);
void foo(int *a);
```

For all the above declarations, the mangled name is unique -

```
?foo@@YAXPAH@Z
```

I demangled to see what MS compiler is converting function declaration to -

```
void __cdecl foo(int * const)
```

So, at least it gives us an insight that MS compiler is not worried until a negative array index is used in function declaration. g++ also should be doing something like this, if I amn't wrong.

Comment: Sorry. Which part isn't clear ? Isn't your question why it got compiled even with out a array size constant in function declaration ?

Comment: Yes. It is. But I did't get your explanation.

Comment: Though you are saying - `void read_cards(int a[], int b[])`, compiler considers them as `void read_cards(int * const a, int * const b)`.

Comment: interesting sleuthing, even if the OP seemed to be fishing for a much simpler answer